# Can't connect to home wifi, other wifis are fine

Tags: networking, wireless, router

I have just installed Ubuntu alongside Windows on my laptop.
But I cannot connect to my home wifi (Xiaomi_Wifi in PasteBin).
How can I fix this? I can connect to my phone wifi (iPhone von Aaron).

I followed [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108) instruction on how to get more info about the situation.

[This](https://pastebin.com/BY04mtWk) is the resulting output.

Thank you all!

PS: I have already tried to switch the security of my router from WPA/WPA2 to WPA, that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I recommend a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

**EDIT**: You might try a driver parameter. From the terminal:

```
sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci
sudo modprobe ath10k_core cryptmode=1
sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
```

If there is any improvement, make the change persistent:

```
sudo -i
echo "options ath10k_core cryptmode=1"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
exit
```

Comment: Thanks! But the only choices my router offers are WPA2, WPA/WPA2 or no security at all. And I am not able to change the channel width too... I tried all the security modes, but none of them work with ubuntu, while they work completely fine with windows on the same laptop and on my phone.

Comment: I am quite surprised. Isn't there a selection for TKIP vs. CCMP, also sometimes known as AES? TKIP is quite insecure and I'm shocked that any router would require it. A great many things work perfectly well in Linux but not Windows and vice versa. Ubuntu isn't Windows Lite; it is an entirely different operating system.

Comment: I looked through the whole settings of the router, but neither TKIP nor CCMP/AES are mentioned there at all.... It's a very "plug and play"-kind of router which is meant to be consumer friendly I think, I got it from a chinese friend because he got a new one.... So the only think I can do is get a new router? There is no driver or something I could install on my ubuntu?

Comment: And yeah, I know that Ubuntu is not Windows*something, but I thought Wifi is so standardized and common, it surely has to work on the same hardware :)

Comment: If your router requires the insecure TKIP but doesn't allow you to deselect it in favor of CCMP/AES, then yes, I'd seriously consider a newer router. Wireless hardware and technology is pretty much standardized, but the drivers are not. Please see my edit above in a few minutes.